# How does HLSL treat arbitrarily small numbers?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, hlsl

First of all, I'm rendering a unit square applying a world transformation to translate it to the middle of the screen. Up to this point everything works fine. Here's the result image.

[image]

However, when I'm applying a view transformation I start to run into some problems. This is the code where I'm creating the view matrix.

```
XMFLOAT4X4 viewMatrix;
XMVECTOR eye = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Eye);
XMVECTOR focus = XMLoadFloat3(&m_LookAt);
XMVECTOR up = XMLoadFloat3(&m_Up);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&viewMatrix, XMMatrixLookAtLH(eye, eye + focus, up));
```

And so I tracked the problem down to the creation of the *lookAt* vector in the following code.

```
float x = cos(XMConvertToRadians(m_Yaw)) * cos(XMConvertToRadians(m_Pitch));
float y = sin(XMConvertToRadians(m_Pitch));
float z = sin(XMConvertToRadians(m_Yaw)) * cos(XMConvertToRadians(m_Pitch));
XMVECTOR m_LookAt = -XMVector3Normalize(XMVectorSet(x, y, z, 0.0f));
```

---

Applying the following parameters...

- `m_Yaw = -90.0f`
- `m_Pitch = 0.0f`
- `m_Eye = (0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f)`

... result in a `(-4.37113883e-008, 0.0, -1.0)` *lookAt* vector, in a

```
{             1.0, 0.0, 4.37113883e-008, 0.0}
{             0.0, 1.0,             0.0, 0.0}
{-4.37113883e-008, 0.0,             1.0, 0.0}
{-2.18556949e-007, 0.0,             5.0, 1.0}
```

view matrix and the following image.

[image]

So, I tried to create a hardcoded *lookAt* vector with the same *m_Yaw* and *m_Pitch* parameters.

```
x = cos(-90) * cos(0) = 0 * 1 = 0
y = sin(0) = 0
z = sin(-90) * cos(0) = -1 * 1 = -1
```

The only difference is that the *x* value resulted in `0` instead of `-4.37113883e-008`, which I believe is due to the conversion to radians. This alone "fixes" the problem and the result image is identical to the first one.

However, since I cannot keep these values fixed. I created a small constant `const float kEpsilon = 0.0001f;` and clamped to zero any components from the *lookAt* vector that are smaller than `kEpsilon` and bigger than `-kEpsilon`.

```
XMVECTOR lookAt = XMVectorSet(
    x < kEpsilon && x > -kEpsilon ? 0.0f : x,
    y < kEpsilon && y > -kEpsilon ? 0.0f : y,
    z < kEpsilon && z > -kEpsilon ? 0.0f : z,
    0.0f
);
```

But this feels like a cheap solution and I still don't understand why this bug was ocurring. Is this due to any particularity of DirectX that I might be unaware of? Or the error is in my code?

Additional information:

- Vertex shader: https://pastebin.com/Lrd79HMB

Comment: How do you calculate your projection matrix? Maybe if you modify near and far parameters there, then you won't need this fix.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have small numbers like this. And they won't affect the result in the way you described. You have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: @VuVirt I'm not using a projection matrix yet. These images were rendered using only a world and a view matrix.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko I tried applying the matrices in C++ instead of passing them to the shaders which resulted in the same problem. Aside from passing them in a constant buffer to the vertex shader, there are no other steps they're going through as far as I know.

Comment: @JeanCatanho I still think it's a near far clipping problem

Comment: Shader Model 4.0 or later conforms to IEEE 754 floating-point numbers--although doubles and denormals can be very slow on some hardware. Be sure to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @JeanCatanho It looks like your quad clipped be near or far plane. Try to make RenderDoc capture and check depth failed pixels for this draw call.